# Different testing and training accuracy values within a NN TensorFlow structure

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, accuracy

In order to select the optimum number of my gradient descent algorithm, I had used a for loop of 1500 iterations and each 100 iterations training and testing accuracies are printed. Here everything is ok than I selected my iteration number that gave me 95% for training and 91% for testing and I had evaluated my trained model using the next code:

```
for i in range(0,half):
    x_train = np.reshape(Train_dat[i,:],[1,500])
    t_train = np.reshape(Train_target[i,:],[1,6])
    train= {x: x_train, t:  t_train}
    evaluation= pred.eval(feed_dict=train,session=session)
    est_classTrain[i] = np.argmax(evaluation)
    x_test=np.reshape(Test_dat[i,:],[1,500])
    t_test = np.reshape(Test_target[i,:],[1,6])
    test= {x: x_test, t: t_test}
    evalua= pred.eval(feed_dict=test,session=session)
    est_classTest[i] = np.argmax(evalua[0])
```

The problem is that after executing the above code performances have been reduced to 90% and 69% for training and testing, respectively.
My question is why I got different values?